# find nth number from string and split the ['8','th'] like this using dart

Tags: regex, function, dart

I have a string

final String title = 'byron48th';

now write a fuction that provider output like this =['b','y','r','o','n','4','8','th']

we need to splith 'nd','th','st' on a single string if there is before any number available.

=['b','y','r','o','n','4','8','th']

Comment: Should you perhaps also split`rd` (as in `23rd`) as a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try a regex match all on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\d)(?:st|th|nd)|.
```

This matches the suffixes `st`, `th`, or `nd`, when they are preceded by a number.  That match failing, the regex matches any single character.

Sample script:

```
String x = "byron48th";
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'(?<=\d)(?:st|th|nd)|.');
var macthes = regExp.allMatches(x).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList();
print(macthes);
```

Comment: Should you perhaps also have `rd` in your alternation?

Answer (score 0):

You may try splitting your string using this regex:

```
(?=(?<=.).)(?<!\d(?=th|nd|st|rd).)
```

It finds all boundaries between two characters, and excludes the ones that preceded by a number and followed by either of `th|nd|st|rd`.

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/ovf0WA/1)

Using it in dart

```dart
text.split(new RegExp(r"(?=(?<=.).)(?<!\d(?=th|nd|st|rd).)"))
```